# Revolut Checkout integration - embed.js on sandbox not found

Tags: javascript, integration, embed, payment-gateway

I am trying to integrate the Revolut Merchant API along with the Checkout widget.
The backend part does its job well, and I receive the public_id correctly, however I cannot get the Checkout popup to work.

This seems to be due to the fact that https://sandbox-merchant.revolut.com/embed.js gives 404 instead of the actual js code.

I need to use the embed script option, as npm wouldn't work in the environment I have to deal with.

The prod and dev endpoints for the embed.js are working well, but at the moment I have only a sandbox account to use, so I cannot use those during the integration phase.

Do you have any suggestion if the sandbox url for the js file has been changed? Is it possibly accessible somewhere else?

Did anyone else have trouble with this? If yes, how did you resolve it?

Thank you in advance,
GP